# How do I reliably check if a textarea element has any inner text in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Apparently,

```
if (!($('#myTextArea').html()))
    alert("Textarea empty");
```

doesn't work.

Comment: It works for me. Can you show your HTML too? (proof: http://jsfiddle.net/wATY4/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for html, it's best to check it's length:

```
if (!$('#myTextArea').html().length)
```

However, since a textarea is a form element, it will have a value, so you should always use use `.val`:

```
if (!$('#myTextArea').val())
    alert('Textarea empty');
```

Comment: Never use `html()` to get the value of a textarea. It does not update to reflect the current value of the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

try those maybe it helps

```
if (($('#myTextArea').html()==""))

    alert("Textarea empty");


if (($('#myTextArea').text()==""))

    alert("Textarea empty");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Always** use `val()` or the plain DOM `value` property. Any other property such as `innerText`, `textContent` or `innerHTML` (as used by jQuery's `html()` method) will not update to reflect the current value of of the textarea.

For your example:

```
if ($('#myTextArea').val() == "") {
    alert("Textarea empty");
}
```